# Can't get froogaloop to work

Tags: javascript, vimeo, froogaloop

I feel a bit silly, because this seems so simple, but I have a vimeo video embedded this way:

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/139326546?api=1" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There are no other videos or iframes on the page. I try to start the video this way:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var iframe = document.getElementById('video');
    var player = $f(iframe);
    player.api("play");
});
```

Nothing happens. Of course I referenced froogaloop in the head of the page. I don't use jquery. As far as I understood, froogaloop should work on its own.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are attempting to play the video before it is ready. I would suggest that you listen for the `ready` event before calling `player.api()`:

```js
var player = $f(iframe);

// Play the video as soon as it's ready
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
  player.api('play');
});
```